# How to customize a loss function with a trainable parameter?

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I want to customize the following loss function with a training parameter, where λ is the regularization term and w is a trainable parameter. I customize the loss layer and add the loss into my model. But, it occurs the following errors. I don't know where the wrong is and whether my this custom loss layer is right?

Loss function = binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred) + λ|w|

1.I customize a loss layer.

```
class BCLoss(Layer):

def __init__(self,gamma_init='zero',lamada = 0.00005,**kwargs):
    self.gamma_init = initializations.get(gamma_init)
    self.lamada = lamada
    super(BCLoss, self).__init__(**kwargs)
def build(self, input_shape):
    self.gamma_init = self.add_weight(name='gamma',
                                 shape=(1,),
                                 initializer='uniform',
                                 trainable=True)
    super(BCLoss,self).build(input_shape)

def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
    y_true, y_pred = inputs
    loss = K.mean(K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred), axis=-1) + self.lamada* K.abs(self.gamma_init)
    return loss

def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    return input_shape
```

2.Training the model

```
    def build_model(self):
    img_input = layers.Input(shape=self.input_shape, name='img_input')
    y_true = layers.Input(shape=(1,),name='y_true')
    nb_channels = self.growth_rate

    # Initial convolution layer
    layer_1 = layers.Convolution2D(2 * self.growth_rate, (1, 1), strides=(2, 2),
                             kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(self.weight_decay))(img_input)

    average_1 = layers.AveragePooling2D((2, 2), strides=(4, 4))(layer_1)

    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(layer_1)
    x = layers.Activation('relu')(x)

    x = layers.MaxPooling2D()(x)

    # Building dense blocks
    skip_layer = [average_1]

    for block in range(self.dense_blocks - 1):
        # Add dense block
        x, nb_channels = self.dense_block(x, self.dense_layers[block], nb_channels, self.growth_rate,
                                          self.dropout_rate, self.bottleneck, self.weight_decay)

        # Add transition_block
        x_left,x_right = self.transition_layer(x, nb_channels, self.dropout_rate, self.compression, self.weight_decay)
        x = x_left
        nb_channels = int(nb_channels * self.compression)
        skip_layer.append(x_right)
    # Add last dense block without transition but for that with global average pooling
    x, nb_channels = self.dense_block(x, self.dense_layers[-1], nb_channels,
                                      self.growth_rate, self.dropout_rate, self.weight_decay,skip_layer =skip_layer)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = layers.Activation('relu')(x)
    x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    x = layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
    y_pred = layers.Dense(self.nb_classes, activation='sigmoid')(x)

    model = keras.Model(inputs=[img_input,y_true], outputs=y_pred, name='densenet')

    loss = BCLoss()([y_true,y_pred])
    model.add_loss(loss)
    return model
```

3.compile model

```
model.compile(loss=None, optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001), metrics=['accuracy'])
```

4. The error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "G:/Workspace/workspace_python/Lung_EGRF/train.py", line 109, in <module>
train_model(config['training_data'],config['testing_data'], config['model_file'],config['input_shape'])
File "G:/Workspace/workspace_python/Lung_EGRF/train.py", line 97, in train_model
early_stopping_patience=50))
File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1418, in fit_generator
initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_generator.py", line 217, in fit_generator
class_weight=class_weight)
File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1211, in train_on_batch
class_weight=class_weight)
File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 789, in _standardize_user_data
exception_prefix='target')
File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 63, in standardize_input_data
'expected no data, but got:', data)
ValueError: ('Error when checking model target: expected no data, but got:', 
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0,
   1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], dtype=int64))

 Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. It will be much easier to help you with this if you can specify what it is you are trying to customise the loss function to do. You can also make your post easier to identify by specifying the tools/language you are using in the title.